# How can I create a variable that will contained an unknown number of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, set

I have a procedure that recursively generates objects. The procedure takes the "last" object and generate a "new" one, the "new" object is than considered a the "last" one and so on until a "new" object cannot be generated.

I need to save all generated object. I thought to use for that an array but the problem is that I do not know in advance how many objects will be generated (so, I cannot specify the length of the array when I declare it).

Is there a way in Java to have arrays without a fixed length? Or may be I should use not array but something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);
list.add(obj3);
.
. 
.
```

Comment: Should it be `ArrayList<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<YourClass>();`?

Comment: @Roman `List` is interface `ArrayList` is implementation of `List`,

Answer (score 1):

so your code would look a bit like this:

```
value = something;
objects = new ArrayList();
objects.add(value);
while (true) {
    value = function(value);
    if (value == null)
        break
    objects.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a List:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ArrayList<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)